# Inject values in stackB when running stackA when stackA depends on stack B

Tags: terraform, devops, terraspace

I have this scenario:

StackA needs output from StackB
So StackB will run before StackA when using terraspace up StackA all
But I want to define different values for the variables in StackB, but inputing this in StackA.

Stack A

```
variable "endpoint" {
  description = "endpoint"
  type        = string
}
```

output.tf

```
variable "endpoint" {
  description = "endpoint"
  type        = string
  value       = this.endpoint
}
```

StackB

base.tfvars

```
endpoint = <%= output('stackA.endpoint', mock: 'endpoint_mock') %>
```

So, when I run StackA, I want to inject variable values to StackB in runtime.
Maybe this is kind of confusing, so please fill free to ask anything!!

Answer (score 0):

Desired behavior could be achieved with env vars. You can define endpoint for whole environment and use it across all stacks:

.env.dev (or .env.<your_env_name>):

```
ENDPOINT = "myEndpoint"
```

app/stacks/stackB/base.tfvars

```
endpoint = "<%= expansion(':ENDPOINT') %>"
```